# Java: Why can't return array using {..} without new operator?

Tags: java, arrays

I have searched a lot on the website, but didn't find any related question. So I believe it is not a duplicate.

I know we can initialize an array with 3 ways:

- `char[ ] charAr=new char[10];`
- `char[ ] charAr={'a', 'b', 'c'};`
- `char[ ] charAr=new char[]{'a','b','c'};`

1st question is: what is the name of `{'a','b','c'}` kind of stuff? Is it called array literals?

2nd question is: what is the difference between `new char[]{'a','b','c'}` with `{'a','b','c'}`?

3rd question is: why I can't return a newly created array with `{'a','b','c'}`? 
I have to return `new char[]{'a','b','c'}`.

4th question: both `new char[10]` and `new char[]{'a','b','c'}` are constructors of array, right?

Comment: `{'a','b','c'}` can not exist alone in Java. There are no array literals in Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the declaration:

```
char[ ] charAr={'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

the array `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` is called an *array initializer*. It is described in [Section 10.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6). It can only be written like that (without the `new char[]` in front of it) as part of a variable declaration.

In any other place (including a `return` statement), you need to use an *array creation expression*. These are described in [Section 15.10 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10). You can use either an array initializer or an array creation expression to initialize a variable when it is declared. That's why the `new char[]` appears to be optional when you declare the variable.

Regarding your 4<sup>th</sup> question: they technically are not "constructors" (which has a specific meaning in Java terminology) but yes, they both construct arrays (or, perhaps more accurately, they both create arrays).

Comment: for the 4th question: maybe array initializers would be a better term?

Comment: @user503413 - It would be, except that terminology is already taken. (See my answer the first question.) They are both array creation expressions.

Comment: @TedHopp You answered my question very  well. Thx

Answer (score 3):

> 1st question is:what is the name of {'a','b','c'} kind of stuff? Is it called array literals?

No Array literals in Java, they are filling array with elements, i.e initialization.

> 2nd question is: what is the difference between new char[]{'a','b','c'} with {'a','b','c'}?

That first one called as * inline array declaration*.

With second you can assign it to a array which already with a defined type.

Example by me here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/19658726/1927832

> 3rd question is: why I can't return a newly created array with {'a','b','c'}? I have to return new char[]{'a','b','c'}.

Because in the first case the type is missing, and compiler doesn't know which type of elements they are.

> 4th question: both new char[10] and new char[]{'a','b','c'} are constructors of array, right?

That is  creating  an array of chars with specified length.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Syntactic Sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)
2. The compiler fills it in, because it is able to deduce it
3. Because on a return line the language doesn't provide that [syntactic sugar](http://en.newinstance.it/2010/01/08/syntactic-sugar-and-java-arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

1st Question answer:- {a,b,c} are the values to giving to array at the time of compilization.
So, the name of the stuff is array initialization.... and those are not literals

2nd question answer:- The difference is []{a,b,c} calling the parameterised constructor and {a,b,c} just intilizing the array...

3rd: I cant get your questing

4th: yes both are constructors....

Answer (score 1):

```
char[ ] charAr=new char[10];
```

Is a proper array declaration. You could assign charAr to another char array.

```
char[ ] charAr=new char[]{'a','b','c'};
```

Syntax where you do both declaration and initialization in one line. You can reassign this to a new char array.

```
char[ ] charAr={'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

Is a array literal. You can assign literal value only where you define the array. You cannot reassign this to a new char array.

You cannot return array literals because during compile time, the compiler does not know the type of elements you are returning.