# Passing a fixed length array of Strings to a setter?

Tags: java

I have a tree with nodes which are named by their coordinates. I just bunched these two separate coordinates up into a single String[] coordinates like so

```
 class Node {
      private String[] coordinates;

      public Node(){
          coordinates = new String[2];
      }

 public setCoordinates(String[] coordinates){
     this.coordinates = coordinates;
 }
```

I'm sure the solution must be simple. Assume I don't want a special setter which takes two strings and sets them individually, coordinates[0] = X, coordinates[1] = Y. That's pretty obvious. How could I pass an array of Strings to the fixed-length setter?

I tried

```
 setCoordinates({"-44.55", "55.22"});
```

and

```
  setCoordinates(["-44.55", "55.22"});
```

also tried passing
      new String[2] = {} 
and with [], but those don't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to declare an array in-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154008/any-way-to-declare-an-array-in-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to write `setCoordinates(new String[] {"-44.55", "55.22"})`.  (That's bad enough that you should really be doing this the normal way with two arguments.)

Comment: That was fast :) Assigning String[] was messing me up. Thanks to you both. Will mark as answer when it allows me. edit: And I am passing arguments. I just wanted to make it clearer this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
setCoordinates({"-44.55", "55.22"});
```

instead use below

```
setCoordinates(new String[]{"-44.55", "55.22"});
```

Create the `String` array and pass the arguments in curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
setCoordinates(new String[]{"-44.55", "55.22"});
```

That resolves your syntax problem.

Reason : [difference between these 2 ways of initializing an simple array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658624/difference-between-these-2-ways-of-initializing-an-simple-array)

And if I see carefully, you have messedup with your length and initialization part.

You created an array with length of 2. But later you are overriding that with set method.

Removing all the mess ,you need not worry about your constructor part. Just remove it and use only setter if you don't have a restriction of 2 elements.

Comment: I'm sorry but your link doesn't clarify how I messed up. Initializing the array as String[2] allows positions 0 and 1, no?

Comment: Are you saying the argument passed should explicitly also be a String[2]?

Comment: @mitbanip You decalred an array with length 2 and later ovveriding it with setter.