# What is the difference between these declarations ? Is it related to one being mutable and the other being immutable?

Tags: java, arrays, string

What is the difference between these declarations -

```
String[] names = {"Max", "Sam", "Ram"};
```

and

```
String[] names = new String[]{"Max", "Sam", "Ram"};
```

Comment: *"Is it related to one being mutable and the other being immutable?"* no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext)

Comment: The link which @budwiser have given is way wrong! you have string arrays not string constructor!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between these 2 ways of initializing an simple array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658624/difference-between-these-2-ways-of-initializing-an-simple-array)

Comment: @yasereftekhari That's true. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two.
The first one is just more readable and with less typing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference at all. Both objects are immutable, because they cant be changed after declaration.

```
String[] names = {"Max", "Sam", "Ram"};

String[] names = new String[]{"Max", "Sam", "Ram"};
```

In first variant java machine implicitly adds those part:

```
new String[]
```

So the both ways are allowed.